# Python Pandas sum up values from different columns

Tags: python, lambda, pandas

I'm trying to take values stored in a list in one column and multiply them by values stored in a list in another column.

For example, to print all all the cores for each user, I do this.

```
print df.groupby(['User'])['Cores'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x]).head()

User
John                                      [64, 64, 160, 64]
Bob       [32, 32, 8, 8, 32, 32, 32, 32, 16, 16, 32, 32,...
```

To see all the hours for each user, I do this:

```
print df.groupby(['User'])['Time'].apply(lambda x: [i/60.0/60.0 for i in x]).head()

User
John      [15.6908333333, 0.01, 0.503888888889, 4.581944]
Bob     [37.0177777778, 0.139166666667, 4.30916666667,...
```

I'd like to take each 'Core' value and multiply it by the corresponding 'Hour' from the the Time output and then sum up the values for each user.  In other words, have an output like this:

```
User      Total
John      1378.71997155344
...
```

This value was obtained by taking 64*15.6908333333 + 64*0.01 + 160*0.503888888889 + 64*4.581944.

Because I'm a new user, I can't answer my own question until after 8 hours have elapsed, but I believe I've resolved this.

Here is what I've come up with:

```
print df.groupby(['User']).apply(lambda x: np.sum([x.Cores.astype(float)*(x.Time.astype(float)/60.0/60.0)]))

User
John                1678.035556
Bob                 7725.688889
```

Not sure if this is the right approach, so I would appreciate any input.  Thanks.

Comment: can you show your initial DataFrame?

Comment: Aside: `lambda x: [i for i in x]` should be the same as `lambda x: list(x)`, which in turn is equivalent to simply `list`.  You generally don't want lists as DataFrame elements because they're harder to access, but sometimes it can be useful.

Comment: I believe I might have solved the problem.  Here is my solution:

Answer (score 3):

I think it's probably a good idea to have an intermediary column:

```
df['CoresTime'] = df['Cores'] * df['Time']
```

Now you can do simply take the groupby sum:

```
df.groupby('User')['CoresTime'].sum()
```

*This will be **significantly** more efficient than an apply or using lists...*